# Scala map extract value repeated maximum times

Tags: scala, dictionary, max

I have `Map[String,String]`so keys are distinct but most values are repeated. 
For example : `Map[car-> "This is a car",truck-> "This is a car", fruit ->"This is a fruit"]`

So it should return `"This is a car"` because it is repeated twice.

Comment: Should `"This is a fruit"` be returned if repeated?

Answer (score 6):

I did something like this. Hope it helps.

```
val j = x.groupBy(_._2)
```

Then

```
j.maxBy(_._2.size)
```

Where x is your original map. The first call, returns a Map and then you just get the key value pair where the value (map , has max entries)

Answer (score 3):

```
val m1 = Map("this" -> "that", "what" -> "that", "who" -> "me", "you" -> "who")
m1.groupBy(_._2).maxBy(_._2.size)
res0: ... = (that,Map(this -> that, what -> that))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
 map.values.groupBy(t => t ).values.maxBy(_.size).head
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need to define your own ( t => t ) function (thereby adding a class) -- Predef defines one for you.  It's called "identity".

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant but my solution goes like

```
val list = Map(car-> "This is a car",truck-> "This is a car", fruit ->"This is a fruit")

list.map{
  case (k,v) => if(list.filter{case (key,value)=> value==v }.size>1)v
}.toSet
```